# Screen window title using zsh

Tags: zsh, gnu-screen

I would like to make vim screen tabs name more useful. I've turned on the screen plugin, and tried several approachs. One that I would enjoy most was to make the screen name fixed using another load screen file, i.e.:

```
screen -S sectionName -c .screenTest
```

and screenTest file would have something like:

```
source $HOME/.screenrc
chdir $HOME/place
# Screen 0
screen
stuff "something^M"
# Screen 1
screen
stuff "something^M"
stuff "cd place^M"                                                                                                 
stuff "vim -p `find -type f -not -path \"*/\.*\" -not -path \"*x86*\" \( -name \"*.py\" -o -name \"*.cxx\" -o -name \"*.h\" \)`^M"
title "Screen1"
```

The problem is that the title command is read before the stuff commands run. If someone knows how to make the title command runs afterwards the stuff commands are finished, it would be perfect. I tried:

stuff "^A:title TitleValue ^M"

but it doesn't write on the screen command insertion, it writes on the terminal (the ^A and ^M is written in vim using `^V^A`).

Then I tried editing the screen.plugin.zsh file.

I tried changing the prexec and precmd zsh methods when the input command has `vim` to display the place instead. But I couldn't do that.

I am sorry to post it here, but if someone could help me do that, it sounds quite simple, but I am stuck at that even if I change the $cmd, it doesnt change the TAB syntax, that is, if I do:

```
if [[ "$cmd" == "vim*" ]]; then
  # How do I check if variable $cmd has string "vim" in it using zsh?
  echo "changing for vim!"
  cmd=''
fi
```

it changes the terminal title, but not the screen window title. Any ideas? This question is also [here](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/3414), but I think this question is more appropriated here, since it is not an oh-my-zsh issue exactly.

Another thing that would help, is that if I could set some windows not to change automatically their titles, whereas other would change.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "I tried changing the prexec and precmd to when the cmd have vim to display the place instead." You can change the screen title with the shell command `print -n "\033kTITEL\033\134"` if this helps in any way.

Comment: @mpy the `print -n` was exactly what I wanted. You may post it as an answer: using `stuff "print -n "\\033kTITEL\\033\\134\" "` solved my issue instead of title. There are many other questions, but with time to study zsh I may learn it.

Comment: As I don't fully understand what you want to achieve I hesitate to write a one-line-answer. Perhaps it's better if you write an answer yourself elaborating on your specific solution.

Comment: @mpy but you deserve the reputation and so on. You can answer, and I may edit it so that it fills the purpose. I wanted to set the screen window title afterwards the `stuff` commands run, and with the `title` command it was changed before the `stuff` commands were run. By using `stuff "print -n "\\033kTITEL\\033\\134\" "` my screen titles are set as I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Screen User's Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Window-Settings) states:

> To change the name after the window has been created you can use the title-string escape-sequence (`<ESC> k name <ESC> \`) (...)

So (without having digged into oh-my-zsh's modules, plugins etc.) you can use

```
print -n "\033kTITLE\033\134"
```

on the *zsh* command line to change the name of the current screen window to *TITLE*.

`\033` represents an *escape* character in octal notation (ESC = 27 (decimal) = 0x1b (hex) = 033 (octal)) and `\134` a *backslash* character.

According to your command, the following command works in the screen config file:

```
stuff "print -n "\\033kTITLE\\033\\134\" "
```

Answer (score 1):

According to `console_codes(4)`, the portable way of setting the title is to use the VT100 sequence `OSC 0 ; title ST`. `OSC` (operating system command) is defined in ECMA-48 to be `\x9d` or `ESC ]`. `ST` (string terminator) is defined in ECMA-48 to be `\x9c` or `ESC \`; VT100 & xterm also allow `BEL` to be used. So all that to say:

```
printf '\x1b]0;%s\x07' "$your_title"
```

Or if you love inferior octals for some reason:

```
printf '\033]0;%s\007' "$your_title"
```